# User Exit or BAdI for VA01 partners tab

Tags: abap, sap-erp

After creating a Grant from the `GMGRANT` transaction code, after pressing on "Change Status", a Sales Order is automatically created.
Currently in the Partner Function tab, all partner types are filled with the "Sold-to-party" partner.

I need that 'Bill to party' and 'Payer' be taken from a 'Sponsor'.
I tried to find a BAdI or an User Exit without success.
Can you help me with these issue?

[image: IMG1]

[image: IMG2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `USEREXIT_SAVE_DOCUMENT_PREPARE` exit for overriding partners before order creation, it resides in `MV45AFZZ` include. You can write something like this:

```
IF sy-tcode = 'GMGRANT'.
  LOOP AT XVBPA.
    IF XVBPA-PARVW = 'RG' " filling payer
      XVBPA-VBELN = SPONSOR-KUNNR1.
    ENDIF.
    IF XVBPA-PARVW = 'RE' " filling bill-to
      XVBPA-VBELN = SPONSOR-KUNNR2.
    ENDIF.
    MODIFY XVBPA.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.
```

If the restriction by GMGRANT transaction doesn't work, you can play with sy-uсomm command value, after changing the status it should hold some specific value.